# parsing local xml file in Rails, where to put the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

So the task is easy: display player information from local xml file that contains player information. 
I use nokogiri to parse the xml file.

I have 3 tables: Divisions has_many Teams, Teams has_many Players. I plan to create division, team and player while parsing the xml.

My question is where to put the parsing algorithm? should it be in the model or controller? and what model/controller? or it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a broad question with many possible answere, but Generally I'd say to be safe, put it in a module

in lib/my_xml_parser.rb

```
module MyXmlParser
  def parse( xml )
    # your code here...
  end
end
```

and where you need it

```
include 'MyXmlParser'
```